# Installing application in Wine fails on Ubuntu 16 LTS 64 bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

During installation, wine silently fails to install an application at the following point:

`Execute: C:\users\user\Temp\vcredist_x64 /passive /norestart`

Digging further, the temp folder inside my wine folder is filled with installation errors such as the following:

`[0027:0028][2016-09-04T15:43:37]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to open parent pipe: \\.\pipe\BurnPipe.{E789565F-2800-496A-97E2-6760C4AB4AB5}
[0027:0028][2016-09-04T15:43:37]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to connect to unelevated process.
[0027:0028][2016-09-04T15:43:37]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to run per-machine`

Most articles related to this error can be distilled to "did you try wine tricks" which isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to ask, and two things to try.

First thing to look at--is the application you are trying to install known to work with wine? You can look it up at http://appdb.winehq.org/.

Secondly, is this application from a legitimate source? If it's not, it may be corrupted, it may be infected with malware, or it may be a dummy package that doesn't actually install the program.

If those two questions are resolved, try the following:

- Try installing the application as root.
- If that fails, try re-installing wine, and installing the application in a fresh wine installation.

Good luck!

Comment: Wine supports an older version of the same software, which is from a legitimate source.  Running it as root created a new`.wine` folder but failed in the same manner.